# YouTUBE API for Flash not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We have a browser flash application which loads the YouTube Embedded AS3 Player to play some YouTube videos (https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference)

Yes I know the Flash API is deprecated, Flash is dying, etc. but it is currently the only practical platform for our complex 3D graphic authoring tool, which just as one feature plays YouTube videos; and it would be crazy to force our customers to host their videos on Vimeo to answer this problem.

Everything has been working fine so far (no changes in code or server), until 2 weeks ago, where we were not able to play YouTube videos from the app.

I found that the url format we were using so far was giving a file not found error:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/<my video code>?version=3&autoplay=1
```

After investigating a bit, it seems that Google updated their API Services [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service).

So following some directions in their page, I changed http to https:

```
https://www.youtube.com/v/<my video code>?version=3&autoplay=1
```

When my app tries to load the YouTube player using that url, the `Event.COMPLETE` event is fired and the player data seems to be loaded fine, but in this part where the YouTube player is assigned to a var:

```
private function onLoaderComplete(e:Event):void {
    var player = e.currentTarget.content;
    ....
}
```

It throws the following error:

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain http://<my app url> tried to access incompatible context 'https://www.youtube.com/v/<my video code>?version=3&autoplay=1'
SecurityError: Error #2121: Security sandbox violation: LoaderInfo.content: http://<my app url> cannot access https://www.youtube.com/v/<my video code>?version=3&autoplay=1. This may be worked around by calling Security.allowDomain.
```

I have set all the `Security.allowDomain` and `Security.allowInsecureDomain` I can think of (`*.youtube.com`, `*.ytimg.com`, `https ://www.youtube.com`, `https://s.ytimg.com`, etc. and any variation of http and https I can think of). So I don't think this is the problem.

I tried the solution in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594647/flash-as3-getting-security-sandbox-violation-when-trying-fetch-an-external-swf), where it recommends to use this line to solve Error #2121:

```
loaderContext.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain;
```

Now it doesn't even fire the `Event.COMPLETE` event. Only a `SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR` event, so no content is loaded:

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
Connection to https://www.youtube.com/v/<my video code>?version=3&autoplay=1 halted - not permitted from http://<my app url>
httpStatus (error): [HTTPStatusEvent type="httpStatus" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 status=0 redirected=true responseURL=null]
SecurityError: 
[SecurityErrorEvent type="securityError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: http://<my app url> cannot load data from https://www.youtube.com/v/<my video code>?version=3&autoplay=1."]
```

So I think this is a step backwards.

I thought it may be an HTTP to HTTPS issue, but on the other hand, loading the YouTube Chromeless AS3 player API directly (without play/stop and time line controls), works fine:

```
https://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3&video_id=<my video code>
```

Any useful hint will be appreciated.

Comment: What browser(s) are you testing on? I know that, since few months back, Firefox started expecting all Flash apps that load external data to be running from HTTPS server. It's possible other browsers have followed suit. The easiest & **future-proof** solution is to update your server to HTTPS. Your host or site's control panel might already allow a simple "enable HTTPS" setting. Check with them.

Comment: PS: Dunno why the chromeless version gets through (don't rely on that lasting). However since it works, could you not just invest a day or two making your own custom play/pause/seek controls?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm having the same issue with my flash application.

Answer (score 0):

You got the error **Security Sandbox Violation** because you are trying to access a web/server file from a local file on your computer which Adobe security does not like. Check out this [link](http://probertson.com/articles/2006/10/06/local-remote-resources-local-swf/)

Found also this [thread](http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2012/11/05/fixing-security-sandbox-violation-in-flash-as3/) which states that this can happen when the sandbox is configured to be used one way, but is being used in another way by mistake.

Check these related links:

- [Security Sandbox Violation with Youtube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660286/security-sandbox-violation-with-youtube-api)
- [Security Sandbox Violation Flash AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801009/security-sandbox-violation-flash-as3)

Comment: Please double check your answer. To quote the Asker's opening line _"We have a **browser** Flash application..."_.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. It seems that Youtube now has a more restricted version of the crossdomain.xml (https://www.youtube.com/crossdomain.xml):

```
<allow-access-from domain="*.youtube.com" />
<allow-access-from domain="s.ytimg.com" />
```

whereas it should be

```
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
```